# What happens when Goa'uld Lord enters a Jaffa

Tags: stargate

When Klorel was tried in the planet of the Tollan people, he was removed from Skaara and will be sent to a Goa'uld world. Jaffas aren't influenced by Goa'uld but uses them (term comes from Teal'c when he insulted Apophis on his deathbed).

Will a Jaffa stay in control or if a higher power Goa'uld enters they take over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also in SG-1 1969 episode. Teal'c says the mature symbiote will take over.

> http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/2.21_%221969%22_Transcript
>
> TEAL'C -
>   If I remain on this planet, I will eventually be taken over by my mature symbiote.

Comment: Good find, but this was later forgotten or retconned by crossroads, like many other things in the series.

Answer (score 6):

While a Jaffa carries an infant symbiote, they are immune to becoming a host.

Comment: So why not suggest that Klorel be put inside a Jaffa, he will survive but will not be willingly able to control the jaffa.

Comment: @Sid Klorel was a mature symbiote. *Crossroads* implies heavily that after it reaches maturity, a symbiote can't keep the Jaffa alive. I like the idea a lot though!

Answer (score 5):

Once a Goa'uld is mature, he cant be inside a Jaffa any more. But in the case of an emergency, the Goa'uld can take over the Jaffa. It's mentoned in *Crossroads* Season 4, episode 4.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is not if the symbiote goes into the pouch, but what if a symbiot tries to take the Jaffa as a host.

In the episode *Crossroads* 4.04 What was preventing Tanith from burrowing through the pouch into Shan'auc brain and take her as a host.

It is never explained why Jaffa can not be hosts.

*edit*

In Stargate SG-1: Moebius Squared,  Amaunet takes Shan'auc as a host, meaning that at least in the novels it is possible for a Jaffa to be taken as a host.